# I'd like to process my urls by passing values in the url through a database

Tags: php

So, I have user friendly urls for my website like this

```
www.quiz.com/quiz.php/category/subcategory/quiz
```

When a user tries to visit this page, I'd like to get the category, subcategory and quiz and process them so that I can get correct info. Now, by process I mean, I need to get these three values, run them through a databse to get their unique id's.

After getting these unique id's, I call a function using these values that will them get the correct information for the user.
It's important to note that there are several categories, with several subcategories, and seveal subcategories with several quizzes under them.

Any ideas how I can do this?

EDIT: These urls don't actually exist, so a solution that works when a 404 error is expected back would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you written any mysql query?

Comment: Im assuming you're asking if I have experience working with mysql. Yes. Alot of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
<?php 
$actual_url = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

echo $actual_url;

$splitts = explode("/", $actual_url);


end($splitts);        
$key = key($splitts);



$quiz = $splitts[$key];
$subcategory = $splits[$key-1];
$category = $splitts[$key-2];
```

Comment: Will this work okay if the url doesn't exist? Coz as it is, the first instinct of the client is to send out a 404 error when the document isn't found

Comment: you will handle it by some alternate method! do you wanted me to code for 404 also?

Comment: Okay so, thanks. But my challenge is doing the processing when a 404 error is expected. But this should help, ill try redirect my 404 errors to a page containing this code and see how it works. Thanks.